# php syntax error when try to use phpactiverecord library

Tags: php, phpactiverecord

I have code

```
ActiveRecord\Config::initialize(function($cfg) {
  $cfg->set_model_directory("models");
  $cfg->set_connections(array("development" => "mysql://root:123@localhost/server"));
}

$server = new Server;
```

Why I get error

> [Sun Nov 04 22:11:49 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in Server.php on line 27

on `$server = new Server;`

How to escape it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have syntax error on the preceding line - you function is not finished. Try

```
 ActiveRecord\Config::initialize(function($cfg) {
  $cfg->set_model_directory("models");
  $cfg->set_connections(array("development" => "mysql://root:123@localhost/server"));
});

$server = new Server;
```

i.e. put `);` on the preceding line.